# Sharing elasticsearch between Logstash/graylog2 and my own application

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, graylog2

Would it be safe to share an elasticsearch cluster (or single-node elasticsearch cluster) between [Logstash](http://www.elasticsearch.org/overview/logstash/) or [graylog2](http://www.graylog2.org/) and my own application? what configuration changes/additions should be made for accomodating that? what kind of name-spacing would the application require for storing its own data in separation from graylog/Logstash?

I'd rather avoid maintaining separate clusters, especially on dev boxes but also in general - if the architecture allows.

Answer (score 2):

It is technically possible but not recommended. You will experience load on the logging cluster that you want to decouple from the other applications using ES.

Graylog2 supports defining an index prefix for having multiple setups running in one ES cluster.

Answer (score 0):

We have both(Kibana and Graylog) running with shared Elasticsearch. It's just that the indexing pattern is something different we have to add Circuit breakers in Elasticsearch so that Kibana search query for logs would not expand beyond a certain size.